# Правильность употребления слова "тоже"

Tags: выбор-слов

Правильно ли спросить "Машина тоже закрыта?" имея ввиду, что в прошлый раз она была тоже закрыта?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, это неправильно, поскольку "**тоже**" здесь означает "**как и что-то другое** (гараж, дом и т. п.)" из упомянутого перед этим. Воможный вариант:

> Машина **и сейчас** [= как и тогда, как и в тот раз] закрыта?

Answer (score 0):

Не правильно.

Тоже - равным образом, так же, как и кто-что-нибудь. (словарь)

Правильно, если раньше говорилось про что-то другое:

`Входная дверь закрыта. Машина тоже закрыта?`

Правильно так: `машина закрыта, как и в прошлый раз?`

Answer (score 0):

> Правильно ли спросить "Машина тоже закрыта?" имея ввиду, что в прошлый
>   раз она была тоже закрыта?

Если рассматривать без контекста, то, видимо, неправильно, потому, что, как тут уже замечено было, порождает двусмысленность.

Нот в контексте возможно.

***"Это какое-то дежа вю. Я, как и год неделю назад, промок и не могу попасть домой потому что потерял ключи, а телефон оставил на работе. - И машина тоже закрыта? - И машина тоже, как и тогда. "***
Тут, конечно, тоже можно придраться к тонкостям использования тоже/также, но в целом фраза вполне осмысленная.